# While using nodejs in raspberry pi on startup, how to see console

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, startup, raspberry-pi3

I am using NodeJs in Raspberrypi on startup (rc.local). i have some issue my ftp client will not able to download data, if the NodeJs run on startup.
but if i run through command line at my own, it will work great and can able to download files through FTP client.

is there any way to see console logs while using nodejs on startup.

My project is already very delayed, please help.

Thanks in advance.

rc.local

```
`#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#sudo neo4j start &
#sudo su pi -c 'sudo neo4j start  < /dev/null  &'
#sudo su pi -c 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start < /dev/null &'
sudo su pi -c 'node /home/pi/Desktop/RaspberyryPiLearning/bin/www  < 
/home/pi/Desktop/error.log &'


# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
 printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Please Help i need you assistance.

Comment: can you post the content of your rc.local ?

Comment: Added rc.local please have a look and sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the whole path of `node` binary file and of your node app, for example : `sudo su pi -c '/usr/bin/node /home/pi/node_app/index.js`.

You can type `which node` to get the path of node binary

But, a better option would be to use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). It will handle the startup loading of your node apps, handle/display their logs, restart them in case of error. You can monitor them too, stop, restart...